# How can I add a TextAlignment binding to a template with Xamarin Forms?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have this XAML code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<StackLayout
    xmlns ="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:t="clr-namespace:Templates"
    x:Class="Japanese..EntryGrid"
    x:Name="this" >
      <t:HeaderTemplate Text="ABC" />
      <Entry HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
             VerticalTextAlignment="{Binding EntryTextAlignment,  Converter={StaticResource stringToTextAligmentConverter}, Source={x:Reference this}}" 
             VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
             Text="{Binding EntryText,  Source={x:Reference this}}" />
</StackLayout>
```

and this C# code:

```
public partial class EntryGrid : StackLayout
{ 
    public EntryGrid()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    public static readonly BindableProperty 
        EntryTextAlignmentProperty = 
        BindableProperty.Create(nameof(EntryText), 
        typeof(TextAlignment), 
        typeof(EntryGrid), 
        TextAlignment.Center, 
        BindingMode.TwoWay);
    public string EntryTextAlignment {
        get => (string)GetValue(EntryTextAlignmentProperty);
        set => SetValue(EntryTextAlignmentProperty, value); }
}
```

There's is more code in the template but I just included what was being used for this question.

What I am trying to do is to set the value of the EntryTextAlignment to "Center" like this:

```
<t:EntryGrid EntryTextAlignment="Start"
             HeightRequest="150" />
```

But it's not taking my request and the text is vertically aligned in the Center.

Does anyone have any idea what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: `EntryText="Start"`, for that is the name of your BindableProperty

Comment: What is your EntryGrid? Could you provide more code for that and provide the code about how to use it in xaml?

Answer (score 0):

TextAligment Property is Enum, TextAlignment. To bind it correctly you will need to change it from String to TextAlignment. You can also use string, but I think you will have to use converter to handle it. Something like this:

```
    class StringToTextAligmentConverter: IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var aligment = (string)value;
        switch (aligment)
        {
            case "Start":
                return TextAlignment.Start;
            case "Center":
                return TextAlignment.Center;
            case "End":
                return TextAlignment.End;
            default:
                return TextAlignment.Start;
        }
    }
    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return TextAlignment.Start;
    }
}

             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:YourApp.YourNameSpace.Converters"
```

In your ContentPage declarations in Xaml, then:

```
    <ContentPage.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <local:StringToTextAligmentConverterx:Key="stringToTextAligmentConverter" />
    </ResourceDictionary>
</ContentPage.Resources>
```

Then call it in your Xaml like this:

```
 <Entry VerticalTextAlignment="{Binding EntryTextAlignment,  Converter={StaticResource stringToTextAligmentConverter}}"/>
```

Comment: I believe there is a property.   It works for me fine when I enter it in as a parameter with XF 4.6.  I just have a problem with the binding.

Comment: Ah, I see it's a new Property, recently added. however instead of downvoting my answer ,which is actually correct, all what you have to do is change HorizontalTextAligment to VerticalTextAligment and follow the same procedure I have given you. I'll modify my answer.

Comment: Thanks :-) Can you give me an example of how I would need to create the binding also:   public static readonly BindableProperty EntryTextAlignmentProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(EntryText), 
           typeof(string), 
           typeof(EntryGrid), 
           "Center", 
           BindingMode.TwoWay);

Comment: I assume it would not be typeof(string).  perhaps you can advise.

Comment: Correct, type would be TextAlignment instead of string.

Comment: I tried the changes that you suggested but it seems to still not be working.  Do you have any suggestions.  Thanks